# Составить запрос на вывод самой популярной песни

Tags: sql, access

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос:вывести самую популярную песню.
Я так понял, нужно в таблице Запись посчитать количество каждой песни и вывести максимальное. Но не могу понять как написать запрос. Там нужно использовать подзапрос с 2-мя count ? И группировать по песням ?

Comment: данный вопрос-картинку следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний: поиск по нарисованному тексту (пока) невозможен.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
select top 1 a.[Код], a.[Название], count(*) cnt
  from [Заказы] o
  join [Запись] r on r.[Код] = o.[Код записи]
  join [Архив песен] a on a.[Код] = r.[Код песни]
 group by a.[Код], a.[Название]
 order by cnt desc
```

Могу ошибаться поскольку не знаю особенностей access, но в целом должно быть правильно

Comment: В Access это не будет работать. 1) Нужно писать INNER JOIN, 2) Когда делаешь 2 JOIN подряд, то там хитрое обрамление скобками.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что-то типа:

```
select top 1 * from (
Select [Код песни],COUNT(*) as cnt from [Запись]
Group by [Код песни]) t
order by cnt desc
```

Но учти, что Access - это вещь тормознутая => запрос возможно придется оптимизировать.

P.S Неправильно называть объекты БД русскими именами, а так же использовать слова с пробелами.

Тебе удобно менять раскладку с английской на русскую и назад при написании запроса, а так же постоянно экранировать `[]` двойные названия?

**UPD**

Вот с выводом названия песни:

```
select [название] from [Архив песен] a
    INNER JOIN (select top 1 * from (
                Select [Код песни],COUNT(*) as cnt from [Запись]
                Group by [Код песни]) t
                order by cnt desc) t2 
                on a.[код]=t2.[Код песни]
```

P.S Изучайте SQL. Я смотрю, что у вас вообще отсутствуют базовые понятия...

Comment: Не скажу, что получаю удовольствие от этого.

Comment: Можете объяснить запрос ?

Comment: @babls, в подзапросе получаем номер песни и кол-во встречаемости, а во внешнем сортируем по убыванию и берем только 1 строчку.

Comment: А что значит t ?

Comment: @babls, алиас к подзапросу. Без этого запрос не работает.

Comment: Чему в академии научили тем и пользуюсь. Ибо учитель дал запрос, но при этом сам не знает как его делать. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Если бы учитель знал как сделать такой запрос, разве бы он спрашивал?

Comment: Кстати, почему нельзя выводить вместо кода значение с помощью AND ?

Comment: @babls, это выходит уже за рамки вопроса. Я могу ответить на многие вопросы, но тогда будет слишком много комментов. Советую поизучать SQL на сайте http://www.sql-ex.ru/?Lang=0 , там есть интерактивные задания.